# Is there any simple way to pass arguments based on their position, rather than kwargs. Like a positional version of kwargs?

Tags: python

Is there a generic python way to pass arguments to arbitrary functions based on specified positions? While it would be straightforward to make a wrapper that allows positional argument passing, it would be incredibly tedious for me considering how frequently I find myself needing to pass arguments based on their position.

Some examples when such would be useful:

- when using functools.partial, to partially set specific positional arguments
- passing arguments with respect to a bijective argument sorting key, where 2 functions take the same type of arguments, but where their defined argument names are different

An alternative for me would be if I could have every function in my code automatically wrapped with a wrapper that enables positional argument passing. I know several ways this could be done, such as running my script through another script which modifies it, but before resorting to that I'd like to consider simpler pythonic solutions.

Comment: there's `*args`

Comment: @MZ How can *args be used to pass arguments in a specific order? I'm unaware of any such capability. That is, the ability to pass arguments like: Func(3 = c, 2=b, 1=a) ---> Func(a, b, c)?

Comment: use **kwargs then. I thought you meant forcing the caller be in a specific order

Answer (score 0):

For key arguments use `**kwargs` but for positional arguments use `*args`.